# How to get a random integer in BigQuery?

Tags: random, google-bigquery

I want to get a random integer between 0 and 9 in BigQuery. I tried the classic

```
SELECT CAST(10*RAND() AS INT64)
```

but it's producing numbers between 0 and 10

*Adding this question as the results might surprise programmers used to `CAST` doing a `TRUNC` in most other languages.*

*Note this weird distribution of results:*

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update 2019:**

Now you can just do this:

```
SELECT fhoffa.x.random_int(0,10)
```

([blog post about persisted UDFs](https://medium.com/@hoffa/new-in-bigquery-persistent-udfs-c9ea4100fd83))

---

To get random integers between 0 and n (9 in this case) you need to `FLOOR` before `CAST`:

```
SELECT CAST(FLOOR(10*RAND()) AS INT64)
```

This because the SQL Standard doesn't specify if `CAST` to integer should `TRUNC` or `ROUND` the float being casted. BigQuery standard SQL implementation chooses to `ROUND`, so the classic formula with a `CAST` won't work as intended. Make sure to specify that you want to `FLOOR` (or `TRUNC`) your random number, and then `CAST` (to get an `INT64` instead of a `FLOAT`).

From the SQL standard:

> Whenever an exact or approximate numeric value is assigned to an
> exact   numeric value site, an approximation of its value that
> preserves   leading significant digits after rounding or truncating is
> represented   in the declared type of the target. The value is
> converted to have the   precision and scale of the target. **The choice
> of whether to truncate   or round is implementation-defined**.
>
> https://github.com/twitter/mysql/blob/master/strings/decimal.c#L42

Comment: Question, is there any way we can generate random number between 2 interval numbers? For example between 10 and 20. Or using the query above will always give you 0 to n-1 based on CAST(FLOOR(n*RAND()) AS INT64), am I correct? cmiiw

Answer (score 6):

Another option would be

```sql
SELECT MOD(CAST(10*RAND() AS INT64), 10)
```